# Compare two strings and store the index in integer array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have :

- String1[] having Number,Quantity,Unit of Measure,Find Number parameters
- String2[] having Action,Level,Number,Organization ID,Container,Revision,View,Quantity,Unit of Measure,Reference Designators,Trace Code,Find Number,Line Number,Component Reference,Quantity Option,Inclusion Option,Type

this parameters I have compare both the strings split them by commas using for loop. I want string1 found in string2 at which index. I want to store those index in one integer.

Please give any idea.

```
String[] col=col_name.split(",");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.csv"));
String header = br.readLine();
if(header!=null)
{
    String[] two = header.split(",");
    System.out.println(header);
    // String[] columns = header.split(",");
    int[] indices = new int[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < two.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            if(two[i].equals(col[j])){
                System.out.println("("+i+","+j+")");
                indices[i]=i;
            }
        }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should add your code in your question so it's more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. What's wrong with your code ? Do you have errors ?

Comment: No errors... i want to store the indexes in an integer array

Comment: I am going in a right way or some modifications in code are needed.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.

For each row in `file1.csv` that is not the header, you want to store the index of the column for which the value is equal to the value of a column header?

Or do you want both indices?

Comment: I want the header indices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the list.indexOf(Object o) method. Example:

```
String[] col=col_name.split(",");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.csv"));
String header = br.readLine();
if(header!=null)
{
    String[] two = header.split(",");
    System.out.println(header);
    int[] indices = new int[col.length];
    for(int j = 0; j < col.length; j++){
       indices[j]=Arrays.asList(two).indexOf(col[j]);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indices));
}
```